# How to set up systemd after failed upgrade

Tags: kubuntu, upstart, systemd

I recently upgraded Kubuntu via update manager from 14.04 to 15.10. Apparently a bad idea. I can now only get a loggin screen.

Startx results in:

```
(EE)
Fatal server error:
(EE)could not create lock file in /tmp/.tx0-lock
(EE)
(EE)please consult the The X.Org Foundation support at http://wiki.x.org for help 
(EE)
xinit:giving up
xinit:unable to connect to xserver: connection refused
xinit:server error
xauth: error in locking authority file home/xx/xauthority
```

I have learned that 15.10 uses systemd instead of upstart.  How can I set up systemd? Or revert back to 14.04? Or to 15.04 if it uses either one?

Comment: Since then Went to grub recue prompt and boot repair would not fix it. I did a fresh install of 15.10.  Lost a lot but not sure what all so guess I didn't need it. Thanks

Comment: @ joe  woodrow: In case you ever have to do this again just create a new, separate Home-partition during installation. This allows u to drag things over afterwards. Anyway, nearly everything is discoverable with a Live-CD and the chroot-method. Just a question of the time one wants to invest. Your system may have suffered a different issue, since this syptom doesn't fit the issue.

Comment: You can revert to Upstart: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers

Answer (score 0):

This is not a matter of systemd but of sddm. Had a similar issue, which turned out to be a missing sddm.conf. Your installation is recoverable, just needs more details from your side in order to find out the best approach.

Can you reach a virtual terminal by simply pressing ALT+CTRL+F1 ? (return with ALT+F7) - This should be the case if you can see just the cursor upon boot with the current issue..

If so, just log in there with username/password (password is not echoed!)

then type `startx'

this will start the desktop-session

then simply install sddm-theme-maldives:

`sudo apt-get install sddm-theme-maldives`

Then go to systemsettings and select that theme.
This will invoke the creation of the sddm.conf in /etc/. Then just reboot
to recover and report back.

Since you asked for systemd:

`sudo systemctl disable sddm` # disables SDDM for maintenance

`sudo systemctl enable sddm` # enables SDDM after maintenance

The issue got also covered in Ubuntu-Forum (Oct.2015):

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2299714&page=2&s=55054a7434483a59376b5851fb269374&highlight=sddm

May  be helpful for somebody having other DE's (Gnome, Ubuntu) coinstalled.

Comment: Other options are "RecoveryMode" from the GRUB-menu or "chroot from Live-CD"

Comment: Precaution measure: "chroot from Live-CD" requires same Architecture (32-Bit or 64-Bit) and same release (15.10 here)